# Can I use a Thomas Cook headset on a British Airways airplane?

Tags: air-travel, electronic-items, british-airways, thomas-cook

I have always travel on long haul flights with Thomas Cook. This year we are Traveling with British Airways. Can the headset from Thomas Cook be used on British Airways?

Comment: I'm surprised that British Airways are flying anywhere long-haul still considering travel warnings and travel bans in much of the world outside Europe.

Comment: Who cares about the headset - you get to fly somewhere!!! Good on ya'!!!!

Comment: @gerrit BA and KLM have been flying for a while already, if they ever stopped at all. A colleague of mine just left towards the UK this morning.

Comment: @Mast No clue where your colleague is flying from, but UK still has a worldwide travel warning and most places outside Europe still ban Europeans or force them into quarantine. Passenger air traffic dropped by over 90% during the peak of the pandemic in Europe so clearly most flights did stop. Maybe OP is flying to Mexico?

Comment: @gerrit From Schiphol. Sure, it's an indirect flight because the normal flights are all a bit odd at the moment, but people are regularly flying again.

Comment: @Mast Schiphol-London is not long-haul and in fact so short-haul that its legality in the face of the climate crisis and fast direct alternatives is, in my humble opinion, a disgrace.

Comment: @gerrit Perhaps, but that is completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Almost certainly. Why not ask BA customer services what specs you'd need in general for your own headset to work with their kit, and even specifically whether a Thomas Cook will work?

What could you lose by taking a Cook headset on a BA flight to test?

Answer (score 21):

There was a time when airline headsets had two prongs. These couldn't be used with your computer, phone or other headset-accepting devices. These days, most airline headsets have a single prong.

If Thomas Cook provided you double-prong headsets, and the BA plane has single-prong jacks, then you won't be able to use them without an adapter. (While you can buy these adapters, they cost more than the headphones BA will probably be willing to sell you very cheaply. The adapters are useful for people who fly a lot with expensive headphones they want to use on a variety of planes.) It could be the other way around, too: you have single-prong headphones you can't use on a double-prong plane. There are adapters for these, too, but again I don't think it's worth your getting an adapter in advance: if your old TC headphones don't work on the BA plane, pay the pound or two for BA headphones and relax knowing you now have all the kit you need for any plane you might fly on in future.

What I expect is most likely is that you have single-prong headphones and that's what the plane takes. If you want to be completely sure about the plane, provide more details of your flight, so that people who care about and know these sorts of things can tell you what to expect on the plane. (To be completely sure about your existing headphones, look at them.)

As for the "may" part of this, if your headphone fits the jack, no airline cares whether you bought it from them on a previous flight, from another airline on a previous flight, or from an electronics store.

Comment: British Airways (still) provides earphones for no charge. (And even the U.S. carriers that formerly charged for them now offer them for free again.)

Comment: even better! definitely cheaper than an adapter!

Comment: Actually, there's a trick to using single-prong headphone jacks with double-hole plugs - it's worked for me on many different planes! Plug fully into either hole, then slowly pull out the plug until you get sound in both ears. This should line up with a small notch in the hole, so the plug should stay there unless bumped. You might hear a cracking sound when tweaking the plug position, but it's not been too loud in my experience.

Comment: @l0b0 I have done this too, but if I remember correctly you only get one of the two channels (left or right) on both ears this way, which might be less helpful if you are listening to something making use of stereo effects extensively.

Comment: What type of audio connector do you mean by single or double prong?  Back when long haul flights were a thing, I always used my 3.5 mm connector, either single (common with smartphones, audio in and out through same connector) or double (common with PCs, different connector for audio in and out), and was never unable to fit my headset. Since audio in is not applicable on airplanes I'm confused what connector you're referring to or why these headsets can't be used on computers.

Comment: This kind of thing [Amazon UK link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Airline-Headphone-Seat-Adaptor-Connector/dp/B000XRX7G4) I'm sure some of them used to have 2 different sized plugs too, just to confound you still further.

Comment: @gerrit You know the 3.5mm connector? Many aeroplanes use two of those. One for the left channel and one for the right channel.

Comment: @user253751 Huh, I've never seen those (I've seen one for audio in and one for audio out, but I've never seen one for left or right channel).

Comment: @gerrit it's definitely a thing, or was in the past. It's not even two plugs either, it's one plug with two jacks on it, so you can't use the headphones anywhere except for in an aeroplane seat.

Comment: Maybe it was to put you off stealing them, as they used to hand them out at the start of the flight & collect them back at the end, FoC - they were no use anywhere else [unless you bought an adaptor] I used to fly so much I had my own headphones complete with adaptor - but that was long before the ubiquity of modern headsets/buds etc.

Comment: You said "two prong" and I thought of the _old_ acoustic coupled headphones!

Comment: @gerrit Lots of airlines still have the dual-prong audio jacks, but often only in business/first class. Most of them have gone to single-prong in economy. The reason for the dual-prong jacks up front is that the airlines often provide headphones with active noise cancelling up there and they're usually powered by the jack rather than by battery. They probably could have designed them to use a single-prong connector that would be compatible with a normal jack, but then they'd be much more likely to mysteriously disappear after each flight...

Comment: It would also be less wasteful to buy an adapter than a cheap headphone that probably won't last very long.

Answer (score 3):

You will be allowed to use them, whether they work depends on the plug on the headset and the actual plane you use.
And on whether BA have an in-plane entertainment system. Although it is the norm that long-haul flights have it.

When you know which route you will fly you can ask for one us to tell you whether it is likely that it will be usefull.

Comment: If you do need a plug adapter, they can purchased on Amazon for a few £ or $.

Comment: @LaconicDruid But you probably won't know if you need an adapter until you board your flight...

Comment: I think the reasoning goes that if you're the sort of person who is prepared to cart the same set of headphones from plane to plane to plane, instead of repeating the acquire-discard cycle, you're probably the sort of person who's prepared to pre-source a small adapter and carry it with the headphones, even if it's not often needed.

Comment: other retailers are available including those that pay their fair and proper share of taxes

Comment: @MadHatter Indeed. I keep such an adapter with my headphones for that reason. I actually need the adapter pretty frequently.

Comment: All headphones I've bought came with said adaptor. Ironically I've never needed it 